# Testing significance of a random effect glmmADMB model

Tags: inference, random-effects-model, glmm

Below is the output from a model of novel object test scores fit with the `nbinom1` (quasi-Poisson) option in `glmmADMB`. I used this package/method because:

1. the Poisson mean is < 5, so according to Bolker et al. 2009 I should not use `glmmPQL`
2. there was overdipersion with the Poisson model run with `glmer`. The NB1 model fit with `glmmADMB` was the best of all fits I tried.

There are 3 fixed factors as below, as well as a `Sex`–`Age` interaction term, and individual (`ID`) is the random factor.

```
Call:
glmmadmb(formula = Score ~ Sex * Age + Object + (1 | ID), data = PGS, 
    family = "nbinom1")

AIC: 394.5

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      0.480      0.195    2.47   0.0137
SexM             0.797      0.262    3.05   0.0023
AgeS             1.224      0.254    4.82  1.4e-06
ObjectPLA       -0.434      0.194   -2.24   0.0248
ObjectSCO       -0.822      0.203   -4.05  5.1e-05 
SexM:AgeS       -0.825      0.353   -2.33   0.0196
```

---

```
Number of observations: total=105, ID=40 

Random effect variance(s):
Group=ID<br/>
            Variance StdDev<br/>
(Intercept)  0.03738 0.1933

Negative binomial dispersion parameter: 1.5958 (std. err.: 0.34873)

Log-likelihood: -189.228
```

**Question:** how can I test if the random effect is significant? I have looked around online, and where there are multiple random effects it seems straightforward, but I know I can't compare the `GLMM` to a `GLM` without my single random effect according to info on http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq.

I have tried Ben Bolker's `varprof` function in the reef-fish example:

```
varprof(PGS.nbinom1)
Error in varprof(PGS.nbinom1) : <br/>
  trying to get slot "deviance" from an object (class "glmmadmb") that is not an S4 object
```

As well as his `simulate.glm(PGS.nbinom1)`:

```
simulate.glm(PGS.nbinom1)
Error in simulate.glm(M1) : family nbinom not implemented
```

And also Jeff Evans’ way, posted on [archiveorange.com](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/rOz2zzUOluek2dZ4lcUh), where I ran the model with an uninformative dummy variable (a column with the word "dummy" in every row) and compared that with my model with ANOVA, but also got a warning message here:

```
anova(M1,M2)
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Score ~ Sex * Age + Object<br/>
Model 2: Score ~ Sex * Age + Object<br/>
  NoPar  LogLik Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)<br/>
1     8 -189.23 <br/>                    
2     8 -189.32  0    -0.19        1<br/>

Warning message:
In anova.glmmadmb(M1, M2) :<br/>
  something's wrong: models should be nested, increasing complexity should imply increasing log-likelihood
```

What else can I try?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Because `glmmADMB` (unlike `lme4`) can handle models without any random effects in the same framework, and thus get commensurate log-likelihood, you should be able to do this:

```
g1 <- glmmadmb(formula = Score ~ Sex * Age + Object + (1 | ID), 
  data = PGS, family = "nbinom1")
g2 <- glmmadmb(formula = Score ~ Sex * Age + Object, 
  data = PGS, family = "nbinom1")
anova(g1,g2)
```

(You haven't given a reproducible example so I'm not testing this.)  However, even if this works it would be wise to take a look at the cautions under ["how do I test whether a random effect is significant?](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#randomsig) on the GLMM FAQ (i.e., statistical/inferential issues rather than computational ones).

Comment: thank you so much! I ran your solution, and it seemed to "work", but I got a message saying "Estimated covariance matrix may not be positive definite" for the GLM, is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: if the results look sensible, proceed with caution.